# May i mock such a method?

Tags: .net, stub

I need help on this situation, i need to stub ExecutionAction, may i do this somehow?

```
public string ExecuteAction(...)
{
var email = GetField(userId);
return email.ExecutionAction(...);
}

private Action GetField(Guid id)
{
...
}
```

Comment: Yes, you may mock such a method. Why do you ask? Mocks and stubs are slightly different things by the way (I noticed you said **mock** in the title and **stub** in the tags).

Comment: Actually, it depends on the way clients use the class containing ExecutionAction method (via concrete type, via interface, via reflection, etc.). Can share a bit more code? Including the class declaration and an example of calling this class.